# Scala & Finatra: send file server response directly from disk to network w/o loading into memory

Tags: java, scala, memory, jvm, finatra

I was tasked at work to send our clients a file via finatra, directly from disk without loading into memory(these are very large files). Here are my questions:

0) How do I interact with the disk i/o without ever loading the information into memory?

1) When connecting a file inputstream to an http outputstream, does that actually load memory into ram?

2) I thought everything has to be loaded into memory to work with, transport, and send. How can one actually send contents directly to a network port w/o being loaded into memory?

3) Would the flow of memory be from the disk, to the cpu registers, onto network adapters buffer for it to be sent? How do I ensure that this is the flow without loading ram?

4) Is it possible to do this in Finatra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unfortunately not possible with Finatra 1.6. Streaming seems to be on the roadmap for 2.0, but there is no official word on its release. Right now, `Request => Response` relies on memorized inputs and outputs. The most efficient way to deal with bodies in Finatra is to keep them in `ChannelBuffers` so that there is at least only one instance of the bytes materialized.